# Categories in Data Frame View?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a field that contains various category names, lets say A, B, C, etc... I want to be able to know which categories are in the current data frame view.

How should I go about doing this?

I'm using ArcMap 10.5

Comment: Are you using Data View or Layout View?  If it’s Layout View, have you added a legend that includes the layer that you have categorized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the layer in the ArcMap Table of Contents and choose Properties. Then click the Symbology tab. Then follow the instructions here: [Using Unique values to display categories](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/drawing-a-layer-using-categories.htm)

This will visually display the data categories in the data frame.